# Better way to resolve Angular route within the same component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Basically my intent is to call a function within the same `Angular` (v 9.1) component with the route param, for routes like `host/:route`.

I have the following route in `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: ':route', component: AppComponent }
];
```

also *reload* behaviour for same url navigation:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
    {
      onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
    })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

and this is how I subscribe to the routing events within `ngOnInit`:

```
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        let route = this.route;
        while (route.firstChild) {
          route = route.firstChild;
        }
        if (!this.routeMappginInitialized) {
          route.params.subscribe(param => {
            if (param.route !== undefined) {
              this.mapRouteToNavigation(param.route);
            }
          });
          this.routeMappginInitialized = true;
        }
      }
    });
```

This actually works, but I wonder if it is the best solution, while most web frameworks I worked with, made it easy to access/map route parameters.

I also tried:

```
this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('route');
```

but it always returns **undefined**.

Answer (score 0):

The `AppComponent` is the bootstrapped component so you shouldn't be trying to load it with a route. Fix this design problem and it should work, there's nothing else wrong in your code.

Comment: Generally you might want to do dedicated components for specific views. However in this small example I have all the content on one page, within the `AppComponent` and while you can scroll to a specific section, you should also be able to use the navigation to it. Yes I know there are `anchor` links for this behavior, but I wanted a better UX.